# Junit 5: Expected exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown

Tags: java, junit5

I have very strange behavior for the following test:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

public class TestLogger {
    static IPcdsLogger logger;
    static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLogger.class);

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        logger = PcdsLoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("src/test/resources/temp/test.log"));
        writer.print("");
        writer.close();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void deleteFile() throws IOException {
        logger.close();
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("src/test/resources/temp"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJsonParams() throws IOException {

        logger.builder()
                .add("hello", "world")
                .add("bob", "alice")
                .debug("wtf");


        assertEquals("world", readLine(0).get("hello"));
        assertEquals("alice", readLine(0).get("bob"));

    }


    @Test
    public void testLogLevelTraceCheck() {
        logger.traceLevel()
                .ifPresent(b -> b.add("hello", "world").trace());
        assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () -> readLine(0));
    }

    private JSONObject readLine(int lineNo) throws IOException  {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/test/resources/temp/test.log"))) {
            String line = lines.skip(lineNo).findFirst().get();
            return new JSONObject(line);
        }
    }
```

When I run the test individually, it passes.
When I run all the tests, on the second run I get the following error for the testLogLevelTraceCheck:

```
Expected java.util.NoSuchElementException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.util.NoSuchElementException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:71)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3082)
```

I thought it was enough to reinstantiate the logger in @BeforeEach, but somehow it doesn't happen all the time this.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `@AfterAll` runs after the whole test class finishes, not after each individual test. And your `readLine()` method seems to find the `hello` from the `testJsonParams()` method

Answer (score 0):

If it does not throw, it could mean that the file is actually there and has some content. This makes sense, since just calling `PcdsLoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLogger.class)` does not seem to guarantee to delete the logfile then.

Comment: I have also a method deleteFile which is annotated with @AfterAll

Comment: To write correct tests, perhaps you could do research if your assumptions, on which the tests are based on, are actually true. If you are not sure how to do this, you could always try to conduct proof of concepts. Usage of @AfterAll seems to be only one misunderstood element in your piece of code (Logging, File, FileUtils).